# Looking for query using sed to delete all entries other than last occurence

Tags: sed

I have a text file with contents as

```
backup=test1
backup=test2
sample=sample_test1
backup=test3
backup=test4
```

And it keeps incrementing.

I want to delete all the lines with text backup and have the last occurrence of backup in this text file.

I have been using
`sed -i '/backup/d' text` for deleting all the contents. But I need to preserve the last occurrence. How can I do that?

Expecting sample response in the output file should be as below

```
sample=sample_test1
backup=test4
```

Comment: What is the expected output if the `backup=...` line is not the last line in the input?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/backup/h;//!p;$g;$p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the `-n` option.

Make a copy of any line containing `backup`.

Print any line that does not contain `backup`.

At the end of file, replace the current line by the copy in the hold space and print it.

N.B. This will print an empty line if no line contains `backup`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to awk:

```
$ tac file | awk '/backup/ {if (n++ < 1) print; next}1' | tac
sample=sample_test1
backup=test4
```

Because it's difficult to know when you're at the last of something, but easy to know when you're at the first of something, this works by reversing the file, deleting all but the "first" (really the last) `backup` line, and then reversing the file back again.

The advantage is conceptual simplicity, though it's lack of maximal efficiency may make it unsuitable if the file is extremely large.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cache last occurence in pattern space. My sed skillz resulted in:

```
sed '/backup/{h;$!d}; ${//!p;x}'
```

- `/backup/` if we match backup

  - `h` - copy pattern space to hold space
  - `$!` - if not last line

    - `d` - delete pattern space, start new cycle
- `$` - if las tline

  - `//!p` - if not backup, print hte line
  - `x` - switch pattern space with hold space (`g` would have worked to)

    - then the line is printed on the end of cycle

Answer (score 0):

If using the `grep` is ok:

```
{ grep -v '^backup=' infile; grep '^backup=' infile | tail -n 1; } > outfile
```

This is a multi-pass method and thus may be inefficient when dealing with large files, but conceptually very simple. Note that if there are extra lines in the input following the last `backup=` line, the relative order of this block of lines and the last `backup=` line will be changed. It is not apparent from the question if this behaviour is acceptable or not.